# Flutter TextButton onPrimary alternative

Tags: flutter, button

I just started with flutter and got a question regarding the TextButton(). With an ElevatedButton I can use .styleFrom with the onPrimary property to change the color of shadowy animation which comes when I click the button.
But for my Navbar I need the TextButton, it has this effect aswell but onPrimary doesnt work there so I cannot change the shadow to another color than the default black, how can you change this style for a TextButton?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please could you rephrase the question so it is a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I came up with was changing

```
style: TextButton.styleFrom()
```

with `ButtonStyle` - you can use `overlayColor` to change the shadow when you press it:

```
style: ButtonStyle(
        overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0x00FFFFFF)),
),
```